# android-kotlin click Listener not working to replace fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

i create an simple app to learn how to work with fragment in kotlin
and as usual if i create recycler view i have to create a new page to show the details of an item so after search ad asking some one answer by create interface in my adapter include with a fun that i override in my MainActivity to replace the fragment and execute it on item Click and i do it but after i done the click do nothing but no error 
here my adapter

```
class ContentAdapter constructor(private val activity: MainActivity, private var listOfData: ArrayList<MainMarketTickClass>, val listener: ContentListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int = listOfData.size
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    var inf = ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.maintick, parent, false))
    return inf

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(listOfData, listener)

}    
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(listOfData: ArrayList<MainMarketTickClass>, listener: ContentListener) {
        val dataListin2 = listOfData[adapterPosition]

        itemView.textView.text = dataListin2.title


        itemView.MainImage.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onItemClicked(listOfData.get(adapterPosition))
        }
    }
}

 interface ContentListener {
       fun onItemClicked(item: MainMarketTickClass){


      }


}
```

and here my recycler view fragment code

```
class MainMarket: Fragment(),ContentAdapter.ContentListener{

var ITEMSList = ArrayList<MainMarketTickClass>()
companion object {
   fun newInstance():Fragment{

       var fb : MainMarket = MainMarket()
       return fb
   }
}


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var inf = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.main_marker,container,false)
    return inf


}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    ITEMSList .add ( MainMarketTickClass("123"))
    ITEMSList .add ( MainMarketTickClass(" 123"))
    ITEMSList .add ( MainMarketTickClass("123"))


    var adapter = ContentAdapter (MainActivity(),ITEMSList,this)
    list.adapter = adapter
    list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

}

override fun onItemClicked(item: MainMarketTickClass) {


}
```

and MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ContentAdapter.ContentListener {
override fun onItemClicked(item: MainMarketTickClass) {
        var ft1 : FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft1.replace(R.id.MainFrame,AddCar.newInstanceaddcar())
        ft1.commit()





}



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)





    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var bnv = findViewById(R.id.navigation) as BottomNavigationView
    bnv.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener (object : BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            var selectFragment : Fragment? = null
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> {
                    selectFragment = MainMarket.newInstance()
                }
                R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                   selectFragment = AddCar.newInstanceaddcar()
                }
                R.id.navigation_notifications -> {

                }
            }
            var ft : FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.MainFrame,selectFragment)
            ft.commit()

            return true





        }
    })



    var ft : FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.MainFrame,MainMarket.newInstance())
    ft.commit()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In adapter class

```
itemView.MainImage.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onItemClicked(listOfData.get(adapterPosition))
            acitivity.onItemClicked(listOfData.get(adapterPosition))
        }
```

or
In the fragment,

```
 var adapter = ContentAdapter (MainActivity(),ITEMSList, <Pass the context of main activity here>)
```

or 
In the fragment

```
override fun onItemClicked(item: MainMarketTickClass) {
if(activity is MainActivity){
(activity as MainActivity).onItemClicked(item)
}

}
```

/************/

To pass data in your fragment
in MainActivity

```
override fun onItemClicked(item: MainMarketTickClass) {
        var ft1 : FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft1.replace(R.id.MainFrame,AddCar.newInstanceaddcar(item.someValue))
        ft1.commit()
}
```

In your fragment

```
 companion object{
   fun newInstanceaddcar(someValue : String) : AddCar{
         val frag = AddCar()
         val args = Bundle()
         args.putString("key_some_value", someValue);
         frag.arguments = args
         return frag
        }
     }
```

and then in onCreate method of fragment get the value from arguments and put it in some variable

```
    arguments?.let{
    someVariableDeclaredInAddCarFrag = it.getString("key_some_value")

}
```

Comment: thank you it work with last one in fragment but anther question how to use same fun to pass data

Comment: which data??? you are already passing MainMarketTickClass type data in the listener. In the main activity you will be getting MainMarketTickClass type. Do you want to pass data in AddCar fragement??

Comment: Yup i want that i try to send string like 'any thing ' and git null too